NetworkManager and /etc/nsswitch.conf
I'm looking to use SSSD to connect to Wifi WPA2 Enterprise (on Ubuntu 22.04).
Can nmcli (NetworkManager) use /etc/nsswitch.conf to authenticate to Wifi without user action for on-site mode ?
Thanks for your help
